# is there any program I can use to draw in a 3D environment?

Tags: 3d, drawing

I recently tried out Tilt Brush (on Vive), and I'd like to draw something like that.

I found that Blender's Grease Pencil tool can somewhat emulate the feeling, but since it wasn't made for 3D drawing, the drawing is a bit complicated and difficult to properly draw. (see photo below)

[image: actual 3d drawing using Grease Pencil]

Is there any program out there that can allow me to draw in 3D?

Comment: Not with a mouse. Since its only 2 dimensional. The reason tilt brush works is that you actually have 3D input. However you can sculpt with 2D inputs.

Comment: @joojaa - well, obviously the Grease Pencil tool (somewhat) works. I was wondering if I could get a _similar_ result with another program.. Well, if there is none out there, I'll have to be content with the Grease Pencil.. :d

Comment: You can do same thing in maya with paint fx. But like i said not really fruitfull if you dont have a 3d input device.

Answer (score 1):

It's not simply a software issue, if you want to draw in a 3D environment using a common computer you need a 3D input device such as a 3D mouse.

You could still use Blender with something like the [Space Mouse](https://www.3dconnexion.com/supported-software/media-entertainment/blender.html).

Comment: But a space mouse is really hard to use for this.

Comment: I know, I'm just pointing out that the problem is the hardware not the software, like you said in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can not actually get a 3D drawing done with a 2d device. Since obviously that device only draws in a plane and you would need to project things onto something.

So all applications that you have a painting tool in 3D will suffer from same not designed to paint in 3D. As this isn't a limitation of the tool itself but the input and output device attached. A 2D device is limited to drawing on a projection of some kind.

The grease pencil is not a unique tool though. Most, DCC* 3D applications have a similar tools. Grease pencil is meant to annotate your animations. For example Maya has paint FX which can do quite a bit of complex shading and accepts tablet pressure etc. And it was meant to draw in 3D. But again the input device is limited to 2D so you can not arbitrarily paint in stuff in 3D

* DCC stands for Document Content creation and means graphics suites as opposed to CAD applications.

Comment: I'm mildly disappointed you didn't suggest notepad

Comment: @Cai I have to keep that in mind :)

Comment: Well, really, I know that drawing in 3D isn't possible with a 2D input. That would be silly. I was just asking if there was an easier way to use something like the grease pencil tool to draw _in_ 3D. I don't need anything like pressure sensitivity anyways (Even though Blender's grease pencil does include it!).

Comment: @BeardWix You can not be described if there is a easier way since you do not say what exactly is is hard for you to draw with. Anyway this is a answer to your question as it is asked. if that is not what you want to hear then fine that is ok. But then you need to edit what your looking for a answer.

Comment: @joojaa - hum.. I actually have no idea as to how to re-write my question... The difficult bit is having to select specific points on a plane, (which is tricky because it selects based on your perspective, which leads to the selection being anywhere, not just on the plane. Which is really hard to understand.) I'd just like to know if any other program (preferably free) can handle this kind of stuff.

Comment: @BeardWix in taht case you may try to convert a path to a grease pen. Anway in maya PFX you can just put a plane or any object in the scene and tell the paint strokes z  to project on that  on that item.

Answer (score 0):

There really exist some 3D design software and real 3D input devices for them. One example:

http://www.geomagic.com/en/products-landing-pages/haptic

Computer screen gives very limited realtime feedback of what you actually are doing. The linked device uses haptics to get over it. It means that the device feels like your'e working on 3D surface.  It can be used with specially designed drawing and sculpting software.

This is premium stuff, so all I have seen are only advertisements.